# How to disable the ColumnHeader and RowHeader and disable SelectedColor

Tags: android, tableview

I want to disable the ColumnHeader click and RowHeader Click, I have implemented following code in MainFragment onCreateView.

```
mTableAdapter = new MyTableAdapter(getContext());
mTableView.setAdapter(mTableAdapter);

mTableView.getColumnHeaderRecyclerView().setClickable(false);
mTableView.getRowHeaderRecyclerView().setClickable(false);
```

Somehow its not working for me. One more thing is that I want to disable default color selection of cell on header and row click.

So please can you help me out with this.

Thanks in advance. 
Please find attached images for more information.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should try .setTouchable(false) or seeting the touch/click listeners to null.

Comment: It seems you used this github.com/evrencoskun/TableViewSampleApp , can we have edittext for the table cells and capture the edited text using in thisTableView?

Answer (score 1):

You should try .setTouchable(false) or setting the touch/click listeners to null.

To disable colour selection across the entire table set the following:

```
mTableView.setIgnoreSelectionColors(true);
```